Swagger Validator "Can't read from file" OpenAPI spec exposed by Azure Functions app
I use the Swagger Validator for validating the Swagger UI OpenAPI spec, with the validation status displayed in the Swagger UI:
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://validator.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=https%3A%2F%2Fassetgovernance-lab3o4ydoos5k-staging.azurewebsites.net%2Fapi%2Fswagger.json' \
  -H 'accept: application/yaml'
---
messages: null
schemaValidationMessages:
- level: "error"
  domain: null
  keyword: null
  message: "Can't read from file https://assetgovernance-lab3o4ydoos5k-staging.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger.json"
  schema: null
  instance: null
  required: null
  missing: null

The Swagger UI is exposed here:

Notice the "INVALID" badge in the lower right corner.
What could be the reason for this? I assume, it's not about CORS, as the Swagger Validator requests the OpenAPI spec server side

Do you have any network restrictions enabled in Azure functionapp?

No, I can call the functions from anywhere, including the one returning the Swagger UI: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi

Can you show the actual json?

You can see it here: https://assetgovernance-lab3o4ydoos5k-staging.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger.json
